# Totient euler function: Why $\gcd(n,k)=1$ is important for $\zeta _n^k$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, totient-function

Let $\mu_n=\{\zeta \mid \zeta^n-1=0\}=\{1,\zeta _n,\zeta _n^2,...,\zeta _n^{n-1}\}$. We call generator an element $\zeta_n^k$ when $\gcd(k,n)=1$. Why those number are such important ? I think that $\left<\zeta _n^k\right>$ is a subgroup of $\left<\zeta _n\right>$ if and only if $(k,n)=1$, and that if $\gcd(k,k')=1$ $\left<\zeta _n^k\right>\cap \left<\zeta _n^{k'}\right>=\{1\}$, but I still not see the information it gives.

Comment: Hmm.The group $\langle \zeta_n^k\rangle$ is *always* a subgroup of $\langle\zeta_n\rangle$. They are *equal* if and only if $\gcd(k,n)=1$. This is all basic cyclic group stuff. To see what's going on, why don't you list the elements of both $\langle\zeta_n\rangle$ and $\langle\zeta_n^2\rangle$ in the cases $n=5$ and $n=6$. That serves the dual purpose of pinpointing other possible misunderstandings you may have.

Comment: That's not what it means to be a generator. The definition is that being a generator means that $\langle \zeta_n^k \rangle = \langle \zeta_n \rangle$. It's now a fact that you can prove from this definition that this is true iff $\gcd(k, n) = 1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Ok, I see now. For the case $n=8$ for example, then we have that the generator are $\zeta _8,\zeta _8^3,\zeta _8^5$ and $\zeta _8^7$. But in what those number are important (excepted to say that $\left<\zeta _8^k\right>=\left<\zeta _8\right>$ for $k=1,3,5,7$

Comment: MSE, that depends on the context. In the case $n=8$ the non-generators satisfy $\zeta^4-1=0$. Similarly in the case $n=6$ the non-generators satisy either $\zeta^2-1=0$ or $\zeta^3-1=0$. And they belong to some proper subgroup. And... whichever property comes to the fore depends on the context.